# Setting SelectedValue of DDL on PageLoad using value saved in Session Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, pageload

I'm trying to set the **selected value** of a **DropDownList** on **Page_Load** using a value that is saved into a **Session** variable. The **DropDownList** is already populated and the value is stored along with other info in a session. I'm creating an edit entry page and want to have all of the fields already populated with the info from the **Session**.

What I've done is populate **TextBox** with the **Session** Variables, but for the Advisors section I need the User to enter a number instead of a name. So I need to use a **DropDownList** to make sure that information is entered accurately. I've looked into methods of *databinding, databound, using a data source*, etc but it seemed like all of those **DropDownLists** were generated dynamically. Any help would be much appreciated.

My .aspx Code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fname" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:DropDownList ID="advisors" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="">Select Advisor</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Joe Schmo</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                fname.Text = Session["fname"].ToString();
                lname.Text = Session["lname"].ToString();
                sex.Text = Session["sex"].ToString();
                sid.Text = Session["sid"].ToString();
                email.Text = Session["email"].ToString();
                phone.Text = Session["phone"].ToString();
                advisors.SelectedValue = Session["advisor"].ToString();
            }

        }
```

UPDATE:

So I'm dumb. The Session variable was storing the name "Joe Schmo" not the Value "2". The below code worked for me.

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in advisors.Items)
{
   listItem.Selected = listItem.Text.Equals(Session["advisor"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that Session["advisor"].ToString() is set properly, and returning a value that matches a ListItem value? Maybe try hardcoding it like advisors.SelectedValue = "2"; or advisors.SelectedIndex = 1; just to see if it works that way.

Comment: @dave823 I'm an idiot. Thank you for bringing that up, Session["advisor"] was returning the name not the value. So of course it wouldn't work. I feel really dumb now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in advisors.Items)
{
      if(listItem.Text.Equals(Session["advisor"].ToString())

 DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(Session["advisor"].ToString()).Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: listItem.Selected = listItem.Text.Equals(Session["advisor"].ToString()); Is a bit cleaner way of writing this.